# Simple query running slow, using the wrong index

Tags: sql, indexing, sybase, sqlanywhere

The query:

```
SELECT first DebtCase.SourceID 
FROM DCS.DebtCase 
WHERE DebtCase.SourceInterfaceType = 'ABC' 
AND DebtCase.DebtNr = 'XYZ'
order by ID desc
```

My problem that this simple query runs for almost a second.

The query currently using this index (slow):

```
CREATE INDEX "DCS_DebtCase_1" ON "DCS"."DebtCase" ( "SourceInterfaceType" ASC, "SourceID" ASC ) IN "system";
```

Other indexes I tried to speed up the query time, but did not work:

```
CREATE INDEX "DCS_DebtCase_2" ON "DCS"."DebtCase" ( "SourceInterfaceType" ASC, "SourceID" ASC, "DebtNr" ASC ) IN "system";
CREATE INDEX "DCS_DebtCase_3" ON "DCS"."DebtCase" ( "SourceInterfaceType" ASC, "DebtNr" ASC ) IN "system";
CREATE INDEX "DCS_DebtCase_4" ON "DCS"."DebtCase" ( "SourceInterfaceType" ASC, "DebtNr" ASC, "ID" DESC ) IN "system";
CREATE INDEX "DCS_DebtCase_5" ON "DCS"."DebtCase" ( "SourceID" ASC, "SourceInterfaceType" ASC, "DebtNr" ASC, "ID" DESC ) IN "system";
```

Why the query not using any of the other indexes other than index "DCS_DebtCase_1"?
What index should I try to speed up the query running time?

Comment: hard to say without more details, eg, number of rows, cardinality of columns in question, whether there are any values (eg, lots of NULLs) that could be skewing column stats; any benefit from a covering index like `("SourceInterfaceType" ASC, "DebtNr" ASC, "ID" DESC,"SourceID" ASC)`

Comment: You can try below 2 indexes:
1. (ID)
2.  "DCS_DebtCase_3" ON "DCS"."DebtCase" ( "SourceInterfaceType" ASC, "DebtNr" ASC )
I mean you need create a separate index on (ID)

Please try it.

Comment: Try to create a clustered index on ID first, followed by SourceInterfaceType+DebtNr

Comment: try "update index statistics DebtCase" first, then test again if the index selection changed. if still the slow index, then you need to paste the optdiag against this table here for further analysis